# ant build error "java.lang.RuntimeException: The executable 'android' is not in the path"

Tags: android, unix, command-line, ant

I am trying to build an Android app instrumenting tool called Ella from https://github.com/saswatanand/ella

When I was trying to build it using ant, it shows this error:

```
Buildfile: /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/build.xml

create-keystore:

init:

build:

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/instrument/build

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 67 source files to /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/instrument/build
    [javac] Note: /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/instrument/src/com/apposcopy/ella/Instrument.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

jar:
      [zip] Building zip: /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/bin/ella.instrument.jar

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/runtime/build
    [javac] /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/runtime/build.xml:15: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/runtime

BUILD FAILED
/Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/build.xml:49: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/sioyoo/tools/ella/runtime/build.xml:21: java.lang.RuntimeException: The executable 'android' is not in the path
    at GuessDefaultSettingsTask.findAndroidSDKPath(GuessDefaultSettingsTask.java:46)
    at GuessDefaultSettingsTask.execute(GuessDefaultSettingsTask.java:11)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:818)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

Total time: 1 second
```

However, in the settings file, my android build tools is setted to location:

```
/Users/sioyoo/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/32.0.0
```

where is actually where I kept my android build tools.

Can anyone help me with this? I am using MacOS to build this tool.

Comment: That project is pretty old and uses the old outdated `android.sh` build script system. Not sure if this script is still working in current Android SDK. You should find it in the `tools` folder within your Android SDK. Considering the project age it will likely not work on modern devices.

Comment: I have also tried this on my ubuntu server, which is running 18.04 ubuntu and it also shows the same error message.

Comment: And I have seen this project was successfully built in the 2020, so I think it should be able to work

Comment: Have you updated the PATH env variable as the error message `The executable 'android' is not in the path` indicates?

Comment: Yes, the android.jar and android buildtools are located at:`~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.1` and `~//Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar`, and in the ella.settings file, the path are set as: `ella.android.buildtools.dir=/Users/sioyoo/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.1` and `ella.android.jar=/Users/sioyoo/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar` the same settings works on my colleague's Intel Macbook pro, however it does not work on my M1 Macbook pro, I was wondering if this is the M1's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by editing the
<path_to_ella>/ella/runtime/GuessDefaultSettingsTask.java file as follows:

```js
import org.apache.tools.ant.*;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GuessDefaultSettingsTask extends Task
{
    public void execute() throws BuildException
    {
        String sdkPath = findAndroidSDKPath();
        String btPath = getProject().getProperty("ella.android.buildtools.dir");
        if(btPath == null){
            btPath = findAndroidBuildToolsPath(sdkPath);
            System.out.println("path to build-tools directory: "+btPath);           
        }
        File dxPath = new File(btPath, "dx");
        if(!dxPath.isFile())
            throw new Error("The configuration variable android.buildtools.dir is probably not set correctly. Current value is "+btPath);
        getProject().setProperty("ella.android.buildtools.dir", btPath);
        
        String androidJarPath = getProject().getProperty("ella.android.jar");
        if(androidJarPath == null){
            androidJarPath = findAndroidJarPath(sdkPath);
            if(androidJarPath == null)
                throw new Error("Could not automatically infer path to android.jar. Set ella.android.jar variable in the .settings file.");
            getProject().setProperty("ella.android.jar", androidJarPath);
        }
    }
    
    String findAndroidSDKPath() 
    {
        File sdk = new File("/Users/nicoostendorf1/Library/Android/sdk");
        return sdk.getPath();
        /*
        String[] sCmdExts = {""}; //TODO: support windows?
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(System.getenv("PATH"), File.pathSeparator);
        String path, sFile;
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            path = st.nextToken();
            for (String sExt : sCmdExts) {
                sFile = path + File.separator + "android" + sExt;
                File file = new File(sFile);
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    return file.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getParent();
                }
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("The executable 'android' is not in the path");*/
    }

    String findAndroidBuildToolsPath(String sdkPath)
    {
        /*File buildToolsDir = new File(sdkPath, "build-tools");
        //find the latest version
        String latestVersion = null;
        for(String v : buildToolsDir.list()){
            if(latestVersion == null || v.compareTo(latestVersion) > 0){
                latestVersion = v;
            }
        }
        assert latestVersion != null : "Build tools not found";
        //return buildToolsDir.getPath()+File.separator+latestVersion;*/
        File buildToolsDir = new File("/Users/nicoostendorf1/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.0");
        return buildToolsDir.getPath();
    }

    String findAndroidJarPath(String sdkPath)
    {
        File jarfile = new File("/Users/nicoostendorf1/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar");
        return jarfile.getPath();
        /*File platformsDir = new File(sdkPath, "platforms");
        String latestVersion = null;
        for(File v : platformsDir.listFiles()){
            if(!v.getName().startsWith("android-"))
                continue;
            File androidJar = new File(v, "android.jar");
            if(androidJar.isFile())
                return androidJar.getPath();
        }
        return null;*/
    }
}
```

You have to edit the File paths like you need it!